# Animation about a girl losing time after going to a witch's house

Tags: story-identification, animation

I watched this animation on VHS, 10 to 14 years ago.

It was about a girl (might have been about a boy as well) who ventured to a bewitched house. I remember the house to be black, castle-like, or Gothic, and it could have been <s>smaller on the outside</s> bigger on the inside. An evil witch lived there.

Long story short, the girl runs from the house, only to find out that some time - 2 years, not sure about that - has passed, and no one remembers her. She might have had a brother who aged significantly, or doesn't remember her as well.

She goes back to the witch's house and starts serving her. Also, the witch might have gotten younger.

I don't remember the ending, or anything else related to the plot.

It was dubbed in Russian, and the original language was most probably English, though I don't exclude the possibility that this was in Japanese.

Comment: Do you know the original language?

Comment: @MissMonicaE  -  no idea. It was most probably English, though it may have been Japanese as well. This is not *Howl's Moving Castle* though. It wasn't Russian, that's for sure.

Comment: Looking through the trope page for [Year Outside, Hour Inside](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YearOutsideHourInside), the only thing that sounds remotely similar to what you describe is [The Snow Queen](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheSnowQueen) which has animated adaptions in Russian.

Comment: @CodesInChaos  -  the trope link is cool, but it's not *The Snow Queen*. I remember the house to be explicitly dark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it!

*[Карлик Нос (Karlik Nos)](https://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/50946/)*, translated to English as *[Little Longnose](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0378262/)*. Adapted from Wilhelm Hauff's *Der Zwerg Nase*.

It appears I have mismatched almost everything in the story. The protagonist is a boy called Jacob. The wicked witched needs him for her wicked plans, but when he refuses to help her, she turns him into a hunchback with a long nose. Also the time he loses is 7 years, not 2 years. There is a princess involved, though she's turned to a swan.