# Japanese short film on a robot travel to the past

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I saw this Japanese short film in my home like 10 years ago on TV in Singapore and wasn't able to recall the title of the film.

1. The robot has an unusual memory card that store all AI data.
2. It went back to the past was to save the young boy (the actual robot creator in the future) from being killed by enemies.
3. The robot killed the enemies, it was damaged and eject memory card for the boy to keep until they found a robot replacement.
4. More than 10 years later, the ending part that the creator has grown up and invented a new robot that can read the memory card. When the creator inserts the memory card on the new robot, it was resume and it could remember the creator.

Actually, the creator realises the robot is being mass production and each robot was time travelled into the wormhole, he probably surprises he was giving himself a "future surprise".

If I remember the memory card capacity is 1 TB. In additional, the [robot was] shown as speaking in Japanese.

It was shown right after the Marriage Simulator, not a fully 3D render or cartoon film, it's something like Marriage Simulator.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: A time-traveling robot? Hmm. Sounds familiar

Comment: @Valorum Could it be?!

Comment: Was the Robot a Dog? Was there a person that wanted to prevent this and did they have a Robotic Cat?

Comment: Not a robot dog, it was a small humanlike robot.

Answer (score 4):

Large elements of this seem to match the animated film Big Hero 6, notably the bits relating to the memory card.

We learn at the end that

> Baymax has copied her entire personality onto the card.

And the hero, after being rescued from an alternate dimension, creates a new robot which accepts said memory card.

Comment: 10 years ago? In 2014? I didn't realise I was that old...

Comment: @Gallifreyan - My thought it that most people have memories like swiss cheese. They mix stuff up in their heads all the damn time.

Comment: Yeah, that [happens to me](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150015/animation-about-a-girl-losing-time-after-going-to-a-witchs-house) as well.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Blimey. It would be easier to list the thing you got right.

Comment: Not a robot dog, it was a small humanlike robot.

Comment: In additional, the shown as speaking in Japanese.

Comment: This clearly doesn't match the question, the OP said it wasn't a fully 3D render or cartoon film, additionally this doesn't match any of the time travel aspects.